# Python string adding extra quotes on java server request

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I have Python3 code which calls first API and get response as follows, (dto object in python as explained below):

```py
{
    'id': 8,
    'name': 'user1',
    'some_id': '53gajd563bf8dbscau8a'
}
```

Now I've to call second API in JAVA whose declaration looks like below,

```java
@PutMapping(value = "/abc/{id}", produces = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "do something user", response = String.class)
public String doSomethingUser(@PathVariable("id") long id,
        @RequestBody String verificationId, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // verificationId = ""53gajd563bf8dbscau8a"" 
    // Adding extra quotes to request.

}
```

at python side I'm using SDK generated using swagger codegen jar, which is generated from JAVA applications swagger file.

Request at python looks as follows,

```py
dto = sdk_client.get_name_dto(parsed_args.name)
varification_id = dto.verification_id
api_response =  sdk_client.verify_user(dto.id, body=varification_id)
```

If I debug java code verificationId will have extra quotes to the string. 
In python code, I have simply fetched id and verificationId and added to api call, While debugging I have printed verificationId in python code but it doesn't have any extra quotes there.

Comment: What does the request body for the second call look like?

Comment: It's just a simple call, I'm using SDK generated using swagger plugin which works fine for other tasks. Still let me update question.

Comment: Basically, I'm asking if you're sending the text `53gajd563bf8dbscau8a` or `"53gajd563bf8dbscau8a"`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I'm selfing it as '53gajd563bf8dbscau8a' as i received this value in first response.

Comment: Can you share the Swagger JSON definition of the `verify_user` path? And what does `print(repr(varification_id))` output, presumably that's `'53gajd563bf8dbscau8a'`?